# How to access an AFP or SMB share (e.g. time capsule) in Swift or Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, smb, file-browser, afp

I am currently developing a tvOS/iPhone app. The goal is to browse my local network and find different devices that publish AFP and SMB shares, and read files from them.

So far I have managed to find and list the different devices in my network (like my time capsule) using `NSNetServiceBrowser`.

**My issue is: How can I access and read the information (e.g. directories or files) of the AFP or SMB shares I found?**

I have tried `NSFileManager`, but from what I found, it is not suitable at all for this task… Any idea on how to achieve this, using an iOS framework or third party library?

Comment: I was about to post a similar question. Have you gotten anything working yet?

Comment: Rather than starting my own question, I'm upvoting this one.  There are apps that do this - how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not able to find an Objective-C or Swift example, but this one is in C.

[Tango library in C](https://github.com/38leinaD/tango/blob/master/Classes/Tango.c)

This seems to be able with `NSURLRequest` with a `smb://` URL, but that might be limited to OS X according to Apple's documentation.

Comment: Yes I have seen it, but it was old (5years ago..).There might be something, on the new apple TV there is different app that propose that kind of service.

Comment: Try to use NSURLRequest with a smb:// url and let me know what happens.

Comment: There it never pass in the completion block...`let url = NSURL(string: "smb://xxx:xxx@192.168.0.12")
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            
            session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                
                print("Response")
                let reply = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(reply)
            }`

Comment: No it does nothing, I put a breakpoint but it never goes in the completion block...

Comment: What does the breakpoint tell you?
That you unwrapped an optional nil value, or something else?